# How to avoid getting a noneType error when iterating in for loop in arcpy

Tags: python, arcpy

My program works for one element of my for loop, but once it iterates to the next element in the list, it returns a nonetype to the rest of the elements in my list. I think the problem is that I am changing the list of elements as I iterate through the loop but I do not know how to avoid this. Does anyone have a solution? The code is below.

The database element is the issue not the dc element.

```
for database in datasetList:
    arcpy.env.workspace = database
    dcList = arcpy.ListDatasets() 
    print dcList
    for dc in dcList:
        arcpy.DefineProjection_management(dc, coordinateSystem)
```

The error returned:

```
    for dc in dcList:
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Comment: Try printing your dataList variable before you iterate it.

Answer (score 0):

> The database element is the issue not the dc element.

If `database` isn't a valid workspace, then the `arcpy.ListDatasets()` method will be returning `None`. (This is an annoyingly silent error.) This will break the `dcList` loop, since you can't iterate over a NoneType object.

I thought you might also get `None` by running `ListDatasets` against a workspace with no datasets, but in testing against an empty geodatabase, you get an empty list `[]` instead. So it's definitely a problem with the database.

Verify the database exists before attempting to list datasets.

```
if arcpy.Exists(database):
    dcList = arcpy.ListDatasets()
    for dc in dcList:
        arcpy.DefineProjection_management(dc, coordinateSystem)
else:
    print("This database does not exist: {}".format(database))
```